# what does "= preserve do" mean in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

following this [tutorial about C and gdb](https://www.recurse.com/blog/5-learning-c-with-gdb).
It is certainly a helpful tutorial but they started out with examples like this:

```
(gdb) print a
$1 = {1, 2, 3}
(gdb) ptype a
type = int [3]
```

and then suddenly started displaying this sequence of

```
= preserve do
  :escaped
    (gdb) x/4xb a + 1
    0x7fff5fbff570: 0x02  0x00  0x00  0x00
```

in their examples without explaining what it was. I cannot understand or recreate it.  A google search of "gdb preserve do" points back to the same site.  I can continue following without it but I'm curious what the `= preserve do` is all about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> without explaining what it was

It's a bug in their HTML formatting (markup), and has nothing to do with GDB.